# Rounding user input in form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, rounding

I'm looking for a regex and a JavaScript function that rounds up what the user just input to 2 decimals max, the user can input any number and dots e.g. 1, 2.3490, 23 and it should change when the user clicks away from the field to 1.00, 2.35, 23.00. I've came up with this so far:

This is my regex:

`var pPrice = /^\d*\.\d*$/;`

My JavaScript function:

```
// Function to validate price
   function validateProductPrice(){

    var priceRound = document.getElementById("productprice").value;
    var priceHack = Math.round(priceRound*100)/100;

    if (document.myForm.priceHack.value.trim().search(pPrice) == -1) {

        alert("WRONG INPUT FOR PRICE!");
        document.getElementById("priceERROR").style.display = "none";

    } else {
        document.getElementById("priceERROR").innerHTML = "CORRECT.";
        document.getElementById("priceERROR").style.display = "block";
      }
    }
```

My html for this field:

```
<div>    
<input type="text" class="productprice" placeholder="Price" name="productprice" onblur="return validateProductPrice() ">
<span id="priceERROR"></span>
  <p class="price-help">Price e.g. if $1 please enter 1.00.</p>
</div>
```

I'm having a bit of trouble cuz it doesn't really work and I don't know why!

Thanks for helping guys!

**EDIT**

I fix it by fixing the regex I got in the following answer and realizing that my input had no ID, so I was calling a null value back, now my code is:

My regex is:

`var pPrice = /^((?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?)|(?:\.\d+))$/`

My JavaScript is:

```
function validateProductPrice(){

    var priceRound = document.getElementById("productprice").value;
    var priceHack = Math.round(priceRound*100)/100;

    if (document.myForm.productprice.value.trim().search(pPrice) == -1) {

        alert("WRONG INPUT FOR PRICE!");
        document.getElementById("priceERROR").style.display = "none";

    } else {

        document.getElementById("productprice").value = priceHack;
        document.getElementById("priceERROR").innerHTML = "CORRECT.";
        document.getElementById("priceERROR").style.display = "block";

    }
```

My html is:

```
<div>    
<input id="productprice" type="text" class="productprice" placeholder="Price" name="productprice" onblur="return validateProductPrice()" >
<span id="priceERROR"></span>
  <p class="price-help">Price e.g. if $1 please enter 1.00.</p>
</div>
```

Now it also overrides whatever the user inputs, if he inputs 2.336678 only 2.34 is displayed that's what I was looking for!

Thanks you all for helping me with this! Hope my EDIT help people too!!

Comment: What doesn't really work? is there a specific issue?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't round the number and doesn't even do anything, just goes through even if I put a letter **EDIT** it's like my regex is being ignored

Comment: There isn't enough information, but, you should first validate the input with a regex, and only then do calculations. Other than that, use a debugger - it will be the most useful tool you'll find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## RegEx

Let's start with your RegEx. What you have will match decimal numbers with any number of decimal places, but also other things.

```
^((?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?)|(?:\.\d+))$
```

### Explanation

First of all we declare that if there is only an integer without decimal places, that's fine. However, we also allow the short hand `.8` for `0.8`. We then match all the decimal places and capture the number. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/pY1vZ8/2) is a test for the RegEx.

## JavaScript

I suspect you want to write the updated value to the input field, however you never do that. I updated the code to do that and also update every time the user inputs something to give better feedback.

```
var input = document.getElementById("price"),
    priceRegex = /^((?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?)|(?:\.\d+))$/,
    lastGood = "";

input.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (input.value === ".") {
         lastGood = ".";
    }
    else if (priceRegex.test(price)) {
        var price = parseFloat(input.value);
        console.log("good");
        var newPrice = "" + (Math.round(price * 100) / 100) + (input.value.indexOf(".") === input.value.length -1 ? "." : "");
        input.value = newPrice;
        lastGood = newPrice;
    } else {
        console.log("bad");
        input.value = lastGood;
    }
}
```

### Explanation

Every time the user enters a character, the function above is called. First it checks if the user just inputted a `.`, that is a special case, because it is not a valid number, but may be the start of one. If the text matches the RegEx explained above. If it does, the rounding is performed and set as the new value. If it does not match the RegEx, the user has done something wrong and we reset the input field to the last value we know to be good (the last one that matched the RegEx).

See it in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jkfdmdqc/1/).

Comment: Just edited my post saying how I fixed it, thanks for helping me and taking time to explain it to me. cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you require

```js
var pPrice = /^\d*\.{0,1}\d*$/;

// Function to validate price
   function validateProductPrice(){

    var priceRound = document.getElementById("productprice").value;
    

    if (priceRound.trim().search(pPrice) == -1) {

        alert("WRONG INPUT FOR PRICE!");
        document.getElementById("priceERROR").style.display = "none";

    } else {  
      var priceHack = parseFloat(priceRound).toFixed(2);
       document.getElementById("productprice").value=priceHack;
        document.getElementById("priceERROR").innerHTML = "CORRECT.";
        document.getElementById("priceERROR").style.display = "block";
      }
    }
```

```html
<div>    
<input type="text" class="productprice" placeholder="Price" name="productprice" id="productprice" onblur="return validateProductPrice() ">
<span id="priceERROR"></span>
  <p class="price-help">Price e.g. if $1 please enter 1.00.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Fixed it already and just edited the post, thank you very much for helping anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Hope following helps.

I used jQuery for blur event and to set value, but easily can set with JS.

http://codepen.io/praveenvijayan/pen/doNKNz

```
 $('#txt').on('blur', function(){

    var val = $(this).val().split(','),
    tmp = [],
    res;
 val.map(function(val, i){
  if(typeof +val){
    res = Math.round(val * 100)/100
    tmp.push(res % 1 ? res : res + '.00');
  }
});

$(this).val(tmp.join(' ,'));

})
```

Comment: Just fixed it and edited my post so take a look! Thank you for your time anyways! :)